# How can I find out where the cursor is?

Tags: c, terminal

I want to find out where the cursor is in the terminal. For example, I want to know if the cursor is at the beginning of a new line or which position in a line it is.

I would prefer if an escape code existed for this but it's acceptable if only the windows console API has the way to accomplish this.

Comment: There is no cursor as far as C is concerned. You need an OS-specific library that adds that capability.

Comment: @tadman, This question has nothing to do with C apart from the fact that it is the language I'm using to utilize escape codes and the windows console api. Does the windows console api contain a function that can detect where the cursor is? Or even better, does an escape code exist for this purpose?

Comment: [`GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfo) returns a [`CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO` structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffer-info-str?source=recommendations) which contains the cursor position. You can look up this stuff yourself – see [Console Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions)

Comment: @WeatherVane My apologies, I spent most of my time searching for an escape code equivalent since escape codes are supported on Linux, Windows and macOS while the windows console api is only supported on windows. Thanks.

Comment: I learnt recently that Windows support **virtual terminals**, but have never used them.

Comment: @WeatherVane, most console applications on Windows already use the console API which is older and more established. Additionally, some windows console API functions do not have an equivalent virtual escape sequence.

Comment: ... look at [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) and search for "Report Cursor Position" about 40% down the page.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem to me. What are you planning on using this for, maybe there's a better solution. E.g. a library like `readline`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm sorry I missed this in the docs. Thanks.

Comment: @Barmar I'm building a text editor and I have successfully detected when the backspace key is being pressed and I printed an escape code to delete a character. However, the way I implemented this restricted me in deleting a '\n' char from the beginning of a new line. Perhaps I will change my implementation.

Comment: Use the `ncurses` library to do full-screen terminal control.